# How to use Steeltoe without Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, azure-app-service-envrmnt, steeltoe

We want to use Steeltoe for developing our Microservices. However we don't want to use Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

Can we use Steeltoe with Azure App Services? or what is the best solution to use Steeltoe on Azure without using Pivotal Cloud Foundry?

Is it possbile to use Steeltoe (.NET) with the free version of Cloud Foundry?

Answer (score 4):

There are currently 54 Steeltoe NuGet packages. Some are built with explicit support for Pivotal Cloud Foundry, (for example, `Steeltoe.Management.CloudFoundryCore` has extension methods that configure endpoints and actuator security specifically for Pivotal Apps Manager) some are expected to work on other Cloud Foundry distributions (like Connectors and Security), and some are expected to work anywhere (like Hystrix, Discovery, most of Configuration, and the Management packages that don't have CloudFoundry in the name).

In order to provide a more specific answer, we'd need to get more specific about which parts of Steeltoe you want to use, but the short answer is that anything that isn't purpose-built for a specific feature of Cloud Foundry *should* work. An indicator that may be helpful is that the areas that are Cloud Foundry specific should have a Cloud Foundry logo in the docs, as currently seen on the page for [Connectors](https://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-connectors/).

For what it's worth, we're aware that the non-Cloud Foundry story for Steeltoe usage isn't clear enough. We are beginning to reorganize so that it will be clearer what is or is not for use on Cloud Foundry and ideally provide a clearer (intentional) path for using Steeltoe in other deployment environments.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim for your answer. We want to use Steeltoe with our Microservices for covering Circuit-breaker and Service Discovery patterns. Is there any blog or tutorial that describes how to use Steeltoe combination with f.ex. Azure App Services?

Comment: I am not aware of any resources describing the use of Steeltoe on other infrastructure, sorry. The only bit of Steeltoe circuit breaker that's specific to PCF is metrics streaming to the dashboard. The story with Eureka-based service discovery is similar, but with regard to auth (not metrics).

Comment: Hi @Tim, is there an update to this answer? i.e. do you have a better directions for non cloud foundry options?

Comment: We launched a new website that now has getting started guides that are closer to what you're looking for https://steeltoe.io/get-started We'll definitely be sharing a lot more around Kubernetes in the very near future, but specific platform requests might be best addressed as issues here: https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/MainSite

Comment: Azure Spring Cloud is a new option for using Steeltoe outside of Cloud Foundry https://youtu.be/pYibnDelHnU